# How to detect the value of "useCapture" from an event object?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, event-listener

How to detect the value of `useCapture` from an event object?

I made a function that removes an event listener after firing once or any number of times.

This is what I have:

```
/*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
(function ()
{
    "use strict";

    function removeEventListenerAfterFiring(numberOfTimes, callback, useCapture)
    {
        var count = 0;
        return function listener(event)
        {
            count += 1;

            if (count >= numberOfTimes)
            {
                event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, listener, useCapture);
            }

            callback();
        };
    }

    function functionName()
    {
        // Code here.
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", removeEventListenerAfterFiring(1, functionName, false), false);
}());
```

Is there a way to detect the value of `useCapture` so that I don't have to pass it to the `removeEventListenerAfterFiring` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the easy way; remove both.

```
event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, listener, false);
event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, listener, true);
```